# Mule 3.5.0 With Maven Is Failing

Tags: java, maven, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am getting following error when trying to run mule with maven .

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project middleware-services: Could not resolve dependencies for project ch.koala:middleware-services:mule:1.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.transports:mule-transport-vm:jar:3.5.0 -> org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.5.0 -> net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20080702: Failed to read artifact descriptor for net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:jar:20080702: Could not transfer artifact net.java.dev.stax-utils:stax-utils:pom:20080702 from/to codehaus (http://repository.codehaus.org): Failed to transfer file: http://repository.codehaus.org/net/java/dev/stax-utils/stax-utils/20080702/stax-utils-20080702.pom. Return code is: 410 , ReasonPhrase:Gone. -> [Help 1]

Why is it even going to download mule-module dependencies when i have added provided tag in the pom.xml files .

what is the solution ?

Comment: Well, it looks like codehaus is no longer hosting a repo.  Visting repository.codehaus.org with my browser yields:   Codehaus has shutdown - https://www.codehaus.org/.  Lots of good info there, in particular some instructions on fixing your maven config:  https://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/

Comment: Maven needs to download the `provided` dependencies so they can be added to the classpath when tests are run. Without these dependencies, none of your functional tests, which bootstrap Mule, would work.

Comment: how can i change that to make it work . it is failing on downloading stax-utils .  the correct dependency is  <dependency>
 <groupId>net.java.dev.stax-utils</groupId>
 <artifactId>stax-utils</artifactId>
 <version>20070216</version>
</dependency>
But it always going for 20080702 . how can i change that ?

Comment: Modifying the settings.xml solved the issue . @Gus@DavidDossot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the Settings.xml worked . 
[Here is the blog post about it](http://www.javaroots.com/2015/06/solved-mule-with-maven-failing.html)

Comment: Wow really helpful, that s all i needed for my project